# How do I perform bitwise comparison on variables that are not the same size/type

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I am currently doing a little problem solving challenge in C so here's my problem : I get to make a console program that gets Tetris pieces in standard input like this

```
.#..
.#..
.#..
.#..

..#.
###.
....
....

....
.##.
.##.
....

etc... (max 26 pieces)
```

and I have to figure out how to make them fit in the smallest possible square (without rotation) and the most top-left concentrated in order to output the following for the previous example :

```
ABB.
ABBC
ACCC
A...
```

(where letters are assigned by order of appearance).

So I figured the fastest way for my computer to test if a piece fits in a spot in the map is to perform bitwise `&` operation. If it gives 0, it fits.

That way I can check if a

```
1100
1100
0000
0000
```

fits in :

```
1000
1000
1000
1000
```

I can just `if (a & b == 0)` and if it's true then it fits. Now my piece doesn't fit this way but if I shift it right it will :

```
b >> 1 = 
0110
0110
0000
0000
```

That way I can successively compare possible positions for a piece and put it on the map when I found a spot that fits.

My only problem is that my pieces are stocked in a `short int` (16 bit) and I have to compare it with a bigger type (for example a `long long` if my map is 8x8)0 Because it's easy to go from :

```
0110
0110
0000
0000
```

to

```
0000
0000
0011
0011
```

just by shifting the bits but how can I get to this :

```
00000000
00110000
00110000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
```

a 64 bit int with the same shape of `1`'s in a sea of `0`'s.

Comment: for a tetris game you really shouldn't concern yourself with bitwise operators in order for it to "work faster". It will take you a long time and experience to realize that sometimes the "dumb" way is the best way. You don't have to be Batman all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on @user694733's suggestion, here's an implementation to transpose a little piece to the lower-right quadrant of the big map:

```
uint64_t pieceToMap(uint16_t little) {
  static uint16_t row = 0b1111;
  uint64_t big = 0;

  for (char i = 0; i < 16; i += 4) {
    big |= (little & (row << i)) << i;
  }

  return big;
}
```

I've written a test program to confirm the algorithm works correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t pieceToMap(uint16_t);
void printPiece(uint16_t);
void printMap(uint64_t);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  uint16_t a = 0b0110011000000000;
  uint64_t b = pieceToMap(a);
  uint64_t c = b << 36;

  printPiece(a);
  printf("\r\n");
  printMap(b);
  printf("\r\n");
  printMap(c);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

uint64_t pieceToMap(uint16_t little) {
  static uint16_t row = 0b1111;
  uint64_t big = 0;

  for (char i = 0; i < 16; i += 4) {
    big |= (little & (row << i)) << i;
  }

  return big;
}

void printPiece(uint16_t little) {
  static uint16_t i = 1;
  char row, col;

  for (row = 3; row >= 0; row--) {
    for (col = 3; col >= 0; col--) {
      printf("%c", (little & (i << (row * 4 + col))) ? '1' : '0');
    }

    printf("\r\n");
  }
}

void printMap(uint64_t big) {
  static uint64_t i = 1;
  char row, col;

  for (row = 7; row >= 0; row--) {
    for (col = 7; col >= 0; col--) {
      printf("%c", (big & (i << (row * 8 + col))) ? '1' : '0');
    }

    printf("\r\n");
  }
}
```

The output, as I expected, is:

```
0110
0110
0000
0000

00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000110
00000110
00000000
00000000

01100000
01100000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
```

Comment: Awesome ! It works perfectly. I added `return (big << 36)` at `pieceToMap()`'s last line because I needed to preserve the same distance from top and left borders. Now please one last question : if I ever need a bigger map than 8x8 (64bit) is it possible to declare a 256bit variable (for a 16x16 map) or if not, is it possible to have a 2D array of maps and use it as one big variable (regarding bitwise shifting) ?

Comment: @MouradKejji I poked around on google for a few minutes and found [this C++ implementation](https://github.com/calccrypto/uint256_t), but based on my brief research, it does not look like there is currently a C implementation for `uint256_t`

Answer (score 3):

When you use lesser type (`short int`) in bit shift operator, it is converted to `int` automatically. In your case this is not usually enough, but solution is simple:

First assign piece to bigger type, and then fix lines by bit masking and shifting. Then shift once more to move element into position you wish.

Also I recommend using unsigned integer types, as shifting on signed types is implementation defined at some cases. And while you are at it, I really recommend using `uintN_t` types from `stdint.h`.

So you'll need something like this:

```
// bool type is from stdbool.h
bool isPieceInMap(uint16_t piece, uint64_t map) {
    uint64_t bigPiece = piece;
    // Fix lines
    bigPiece = 
        (bigPiece & 0x000F) |
        (bigPiece & 0x00F0) << 4 |
        (bigPiece & 0x0F00) << 8 |
        (bigPiece & 0xF000) << 12;
    bigPiece = // Do position shifting as needed
    return (bigPiece & map) == 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna expand on your answer to do actually shifting implementation

Comment: Thanks for the ground-work. I was planning to use `short int` and `long long` until I saw your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem with this solution is that when I simply stock the same number in a bigger type, the shape changes

Comment: @MouradKejji Right, I forgot about that. I added a small note to fix the shape. Basically you just have move each row to position. Or check out the Patrick Roberts answer to another way to do it.